# Intuition behind the no convergence of the variance of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, intuition, probability-inequalities

$$Var[\bar{X}] = \sigma^2/n $$
$$Var [\sum{X}_i] =  n\sigma^2$$
$$lim_{n \to \infty} Var[\bar{X}] = 0  $$ wich means at $\infty$ we will always get the same $\bar{X}$ after every simulation. I understand this such as if I have an observation $X_i >E[X]$ I'm sure that I also have $X_i <E[X]$ in  my$ \infty $ observations that will compensate it. is this correct?

What I don't understand is if $\bar{X}$ is constant in $ \infty $ why $\sum{X}_i = n\bar{X}$ isn't? That is to say why $$lim_{n \to \infty} Var[\sum{X}_i] \neq 0$$
I'm not looking for mathematical proof but the idea.

Comment: What is the limit of a constant times a number ($n$) that goes to $\infty$?

Comment: I don't understand your question? just if the sample mean is constant why the sample sum isn't

Comment: The sample sum equals the sample mean times $n$.  If the sample mean is constant, what happens to the sample sum as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: The sample sum tends to infinity but its variance is not 0 . The sum is infinity and variable, at the same time the sum divided by n is a constant. I find this counter-intuitive

Answer (score 0):

You asked for some intuition. Well, even when the law of large numbers hold, so that $\bar{X}_n \to \mu$ when $n \to \infty$, in practice you will never have $n=\infty$, so the variance of $\bar{X}_n$ is $\sigma^2/n$ which will be positive, maybe tiny but not zero (as long as $\sigma^2 >0$.)

If you multiply $\bar{X}_n$ with $\sqrt{n}$ so to get a constant variance not depending on $n$, you can think of that as *looking at the small deviations from $\mu$ through a magnification lens*, so as to see the details. Multiplying that with $\sqrt{n}$ another time to get the sample sum, you are looking at the first magnification lens through another magnification lens, and so now the image will be increasing in size with $n$.

Comment: Thank you,
But if you magnify something that is decreasing (the variance of $\bar X$) it's true that it will give something bigger ( The variance of $S_n$) but magnifying won't make the two variances go in different directions ( one decreases and the other increases as n increases).  This is why I don't find this explanation satisfying. Please explain me more if you think I still don't get your idea.